# `Date` command formatting in Solaris Unix?

Tags: shell, unix

How to the below output using date formatting..!?
Date command output should look like:

```
Mon Oct 24 12:01:32 SGT 2016:
```

Comment: What did you try? Did you make an attempt to try to get an answer for this?

Comment: I got it..! date +%a" "%b" "%d" "%T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date +%a" "%b" "%d" "%T" "%Z" "%Y
```

This will provide the expected output..!

Comment: Accept the answer, yourself to mark the post resolved (or) delete the question altogether.

Comment: and save some keystrokes with : `date +"%a %b %d %T %Z %Y"`